# Are Most Modern Intel Instruction Streams Prefetched Before Being Decoded?

Tags: x86, cpu, intel, cpu-architecture

I have been wondering whether most instruction streams are prefetched before being decoded in modern intel micro architectures? If this is true wouldn't branches become significantly more expensive since the instruction stream would have to essentially be dumped from cache when a branch occurs? Would this make branches more expensive in the instruction pipeline?

Comment: Branches are relatively expensive and this is why branch prediction is there to help you.

Comment: Of course.  And no, only the speculatively executed instruction results need to be discarded, the cache is fine.  There *might* be a cache stall when the branch target is not in the cache, you'd have to be unlucky.

Comment: What would be the performance penalty if the CPU could only prefetch instructions from cache?, I am wondering this because I am thinking about an architecture that supports encrypted memory would be possible if instructions must be processed and dumped into the level two cache before execution (decrypted)

Answer (score 2):

David Kanter's [writeup on Sandybridge](http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/3/) (the first Intel CPU to introduce the uop cache in its current form) goes over the frontend in pretty good detail.  He talks about where branch prediction happens in the pipeline, to hide the small stall in instruction fetch for a predicted taken branch, for example.

One think you said in your question is a misconception: a branch mispredict doesn't mean the I$ (L1 instruction cache (cash)) contents are wrong, just that the decoders need to be decoding at a different point.  (As Hans Passant pointed out in a comment.)

If you jump to an address that wasn't in the I$, the instruction stream is delivered to the decoders at the same time it's being stored in the I$.  Having an I$ doesn't delay decoding in the uncached case; data doesn't have to get stored in the cache and *then* read back out of the cache.  So in the worst case, prefetch / I$ / etc. doesn't hurt.  And of course, in almost all cases it helps a *lot*.